# Test exercise with Spanish deck and coin toss: Is my reasoning correct?

Tags: probability, self-study

From a Spanish deck of 40 cards (4 suits - gold, clubs, swords or cups),

[image]

one card is taken from a shuffled deck:

- If gold or cup appears, 2 coins are thrown;
- If sword appears, 1 coin is thrown;
- If club appears, no coins are thrown.

Coins can come up either on the "face" side or the "number" side.

---

1. **What is the probability that a face appears?**
2. **What is the probability that a gold appears and no face appears?**
3. **What is the probability that 2 faces appears?**

---

Being,

$G$: "The card is gold", $C$: "The card is club", $S$: "The card is sword", $D$: "The card is cup" and,

$F$ :"Face appears", $N$: "Number appears":

$\mathcal{P}(G)=\mathcal{P}(C)=\mathcal{P}(S)=\mathcal{P}(D)=1/4$

$\mathcal{P}(F)=\mathcal{P}(N)=1/2$

**1.**

$\mathcal{P}([(GFF)\cup(GFN)\cup (GNF)]\cup[(DFF)\cup(DFN)\cup(DNF)]\cup(SF))$=

$\mathcal{P}(G)\mathcal{P}(F)\mathcal{P}(F)+
\mathcal{P}(G)\mathcal{P}(F)\mathcal{P}(N)+
\mathcal{P}(G)\mathcal{P}(N)\mathcal{P}(F)+$

$\mathcal{P}(D)\mathcal{P}(F)\mathcal{P}(F)+
\mathcal{P}(D)\mathcal{P}(F)\mathcal{P}(N)+
\mathcal{P}(D)\mathcal{P}(N)\mathcal{P}(F)+$

$\mathcal{P}(S)\mathcal{P}(F)=0.5$

**2.**

$\mathcal{P}(G)(1-0.5)=0.125$

**3.**

$\mathcal{P}(G)\mathcal{P}(F)\mathcal{P}(F)+\mathcal{P}(D)\mathcal{P}(F)\mathcal{P}(F)=0.125$

---

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not try it and edit it into your question so people can comment on how your similar reasoning is working?

Comment: @mdewey I'm not sure what you meant.

Comment: Why not try to do questions 2 and 3, show your reasoning and your doubts, and then people can comment?